# Best practice to insert 20 tables from sql file to YII project to create models

Tags: yii

I just try yii last version.
In doctrine the models generated easly by shell comand, I want to do the same with yii.

Edit:
maybe its something like?:

```
yiic migrate create *
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Start gii, go to the Model Generator and type '*' in the table name.

Comment: where should i put the sql file?

Answer (score 1):

Yii provides a graphical too called Gii to auto generate models, CRUD functionality, controllers and many other things.
You don't need to care about SQL code, just import all your tables in database using PHPMyAdmin or whatever tool you use. then configure the database settings in /protected/config/main.php. sample code is provided in same file.
Then enable Gii tool with these guidlines [Automated code generation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.gii)
then start with creating models. type in name of your table click preview and then generate, your are done.

Comment: thanks,I am looking not for gui tool - its strange that yii only give this option.